# What is the best way to get an empty temporary directory in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way to get a temporary directory with nothing in it using Ruby on Rails? I need the API to be cross-platform compatible. The stdlib [tmpdir](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/index.html) won't work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `Dir#tmpdir` function in the Ruby core (not stdlib that you linked to) should be cross-platform.

To use this function you need to `require 'tmpdir'`.

Comment: That gives the OS's global temp path, but not your app's own dedicated, empty path.

Comment: Agree with Mike, I don't think this is a correct answer to the above question. What we need is similar to Tempfile (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/files/tempfile_rb.html), but for dirs; ideally the Tempfile supporting dirs directly.

Comment: yeah, this answer is bogus. Others are more correct, e.g. mine at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139265/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-temporary-directory-in-ruby-on-rails/8823618#8823618

Comment: `Pathname.new(Dir.tmpdir).join(SecureRandom.hex, 'you_filename.txt')`?

Answer (score 62):

The `Dir` object has a method [mktmpdir](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html#method-c-mktmpdir) which creates a temporary directory:

```
require 'tmpdir' # Not needed if you are using rails.

Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
  puts "My new temp dir: #{dir}"
end
```

The temporary directory will be removed after execution of the block.

Comment: Though I suppose this requires you to be able to fit your code in a block...I like it :)

Comment: from [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html#method-c-mktmpdir)
_If a block is not given, The path of the directory is returned. In this case, ::mktmpdir doesn’t remove the directory._

Comment: How can you not fit your code into a block? If it's too big create a class/method/etc and then call that from the block

Comment: @JamieCook I can image some cases where you want your temporary directory to persist longer than a block.

Comment: generally, a temporary directory has a specific purpose for which it was created (that's why it's called temporary) - I'm just saying that if you have a defined purpose that calls for a temp dir, fitting that purpose into a block shouldn't be hard.

Comment: If you don't use the block, you can use `FileUtils.remove_entry_secure dir` when you're done

Comment: @JamieCook Example: creating a tempdir in an RSpec `before` block and deleting it in the corresponding `after` block.

Comment: @DavidMoles I was using a very strict definition of fit that pertained to the size... you are both right that there a situations that don't fit the paradigm of execution within a block (such as working within testing frameworks)

Answer (score 13):

A general aprox I'm using now:

```
def in_tmpdir
  path = File.expand_path "#{Dir.tmpdir}/#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(1000)}/"
  FileUtils.mkdir_p path
  yield path
ensure
  FileUtils.rm_rf( path ) if File.exists?( path )
end
```

So in your code you can:

```
in_tmpdir do |tmpdir|
  puts "My tmp dir: #{tmpdir}"
  # work with files in the dir
end
```

The temporary dir **will be removed** automatically when your method will finish.

Comment: Just discovered that this behavior is already implemented in [Dir.mktmpdir](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html#method-c-mktmpdir)

Comment: To me, the name `in_tmpdir` suggests that `pwd` changes in the context of the block. I'd suggest using `Dir.chdir(path, &block)` instead of just yielding the path.

Comment: `Dir.mktmpdir` is much better since it will use the `mkdtemp` call, which will guarantee that the directory is truly unique. This approach is unsafe and can result in two concurrently running pieces of code with the same seed using the same directory, especially since FileUtils.mkdir_p will hide the error mkdir would throw if the directory already existed. Also, be careful of using Dir.chdir unless you're absolutely certain your process is single threaded. If you used a threaded web server, such as Puma, you would get some nasty behavior. It will be fine with Unicorn though.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby has Dir#mktmpdir, so just use that.

```
require 'tempfile'
Dir.mktmpdir('prefix_unique_to_your_program') do |dir|
    ### your work here ###
end
```

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html

Or build your own using Tempfile tempfile that is process and thread unique, so just use that to build a quick Tempdir.

```
require 'tempfile'
Tempfile.open('prefix_unique_to_your_program') do |tmp|
  tmp_dir = tmp.path + "_dir"
  begin
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(tmp_dir)

    ### your work here ###
  ensure
    FileUtils.rm_rf(tmp_dir)
  end
end
```

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html for optional suffix/prefix options.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'tmpdir' # not needed if you are loading Rails
tmp_dir = File.join(Dir::tmpdir, "my_app_#{Time.now.to_i}_#{rand(100)}")
Dir.mkdir(tmp_dir)
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Dir.mktmpdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html#method-c-mktmpdir).

Using a block will get rid of the temporary directory when it closes.

```
Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
  File.open("#{dir}/foo", 'w') { |f| f.write('foo') }
end
```

Or if you need multiple temp directories to exist at the same time, for example

```
context 'when there are duplicate tasks' do
  it 'raises an DuplicateTask error' do
    begin
      tmp_dir1 = Dir.mktmpdir('foo')
      tmp_dir2 = Dir.mktmpdir('bar')

      File.new("#{tmp_dir1}/task_name", 'w+')
      File.new("#{tmp_dir2}/task_name", 'w+')

      expect { subject.filepath('task_name') }.to raise_error(TaskFinder::DuplicateTask)
    ensure
      FileUtils.remove_entry tmp_dir1
      FileUtils.remove_entry tmp_dir2
    end
  end
end
```

`Dir.mktmpdir` creates a temporary directory under `Dir.tmpdir` (you'll need to `require 'tmpdir'` to see what that evaluates to).

If you want to use your own path, `Dir.mktmpdir` takes an optional second argument *tmpdir* if non-nil value is given. E.g.

```
Dir.mktmpdir(nil, "/var/tmp") { |dir| "dir is '/var/tmp/d...'" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I started to tackle this by hijacking Tempfile, see below.
It should clean itself up as Tempfile does, but doesn't always yet..
It's yet to delete files in the tempdir.
Anyway I share this here, might be useful as a starting point.

```
require 'tempfile'
class Tempdir < Tempfile
  require 'tmpdir'
  def initialize(basename, tmpdir = Dir::tmpdir)
    super
    p = self.path
    File.delete(p)
    Dir.mkdir(p)
  end
  def unlink # copied from tempfile.rb
    # keep this order for thread safeness
    begin
      Dir.unlink(@tmpname) if File.exist?(@tmpname)
      @@cleanlist.delete(@tmpname)
      @data = @tmpname = nil
      ObjectSpace.undefine_finalizer(self)
    rescue Errno::EACCES
      # may not be able to unlink on Windows; just ignore
    end
  end  
end
```

This can be used the same way as Tempfile, eg:

```
 Tempdir.new('foo')
```

All methods on Tempfile , and in turn, File should work.
Just briefly tested it, so no guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Ruby STemp library: http://ruby-stemp.rubyforge.org/rdoc/

If you do something like this:

```
dirname = STemp.mkdtemp("#{Dir.tmpdir}/directory-name-template-XXXXXXXX")
```

dirname will be a string that points to a directory that's guaranteed not to exist previously. You get to define what you want the directory name to start with. The X's get replaced with random characters.

EDIT: someone mentioned this didn't work for them on 1.9, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Update: `gem install files`, then

```
require "files"
dir = Files do
  file "hello.txt", "stuff"
end
```

See below for more examples.

---

Here's another solution, inspired by a few other answers. This one is suitable for inclusion in a test (e.g. rspec or spec_helper.rb). It makes a temporary dir based on the name of the including file, stores it in an instance variable so it persists for the duration of the test (but is not shared between tests), and deletes it on exit (or optionally doesn't, if you want to check its contents after the test run).

```
def temp_dir options = {:remove => true}
  @temp_dir ||= begin
    require 'tmpdir'
    require 'fileutils'
    called_from = File.basename caller.first.split(':').first, ".rb"
    path = File.join(Dir::tmpdir, "#{called_from}_#{Time.now.to_i}_#{rand(1000)}")
    Dir.mkdir(path)
    at_exit {FileUtils.rm_rf(path) if File.exists?(path)} if options[:remove]
    File.new path
  end
end
```

(You could also use [Dir.mktmpdir](http://apidock.com/ruby/Dir/mktmpdir) (which has been around since Ruby 1.8.7) instead of [Dir.mkdir](http://apidock.com/ruby/Dir/mkdir) but I find the API of that method confusing, not to mention the naming algorithm.)

Usage example (and another useful test method):

```
def write name, contents = "contents of #{name}"
  path = "#{temp_dir}/#{name}"
  File.open(path, "w") do |f|
    f.write contents
  end
  File.new path
end

describe "#write" do
  before do
    @hello = write "hello.txt"
    @goodbye = write "goodbye.txt", "farewell"
  end

  it "uses temp_dir" do
    File.dirname(@hello).should == temp_dir
    File.dirname(@goodbye).should == temp_dir
  end

  it "writes a default value" do
    File.read(@hello).should == "contents of hello.txt"
  end

  it "writes a given value" do
    # since write returns a File instance, we can call read on it
    @goodbye.read.should == "farewell" 
  end
end
```

---

Update: I've used this code to kickstart a gem I'm calling `files` which intends to make it super-easy to create directories and files for temporary (e.g. unit test) use. See https://github.com/alexch/files and https://rubygems.org/gems/files . For example:

```
require "files"

files = Files do     # creates a temporary directory inside Dir.tmpdir
  file "hello.txt"          # creates file "hello.txt" containing "contents of hello.txt"
  dir "web" do              # creates directory "web"
    file "snippet.html",    # creates file "web/snippet.html"...
      "<h1>Fix this!</h1>"  # ...containing "<h1>Fix this!</h1>"
    dir "img" do            # creates directory "web/img"
      file File.new("data/hello.png")            # containing a copy of hello.png
      file "hi.png", File.new("data/hello.png")  # and a copy of hello.png named hi.png
    end
  end
end                         # returns a string with the path to the directory
```