# How to create temp dir in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How do I create a temporary directory in Ruby in a nice way? I would also like to delete it automatically on process exit. Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

See documentation for [tmpdir](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html). If `mktmpdir` method is provided with a block, the temp dir will be removed when block returns. In your case, you would call without a block and handle removal later (=program exit).

Regarding automatic removal on exit, I think tmpdir won't do that for you. However, [at_exit](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001431) should help.

As an example, [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/test/lib/config.rb#L10) does it like this:

```
require 'tmpdir'

# rest omitted

TEST_TMPDIR = ENV.fetch("HOMEBREW_TEST_TMPDIR") do |k|
  dir = Dir.mktmpdir("homebrew-tests-", ENV["HOMEBREW_TEMP"] || "/tmp")
  at_exit { FileUtils.remove_entry(dir) }
  ENV[k] = dir
end
```

Comment: I suppose you could clarify that tmpdir will remove the directory when the _block_ ends, but if the OP _really_ wanted to have the directory removed at the end of the _program_, then he may need at_exit.

Comment: appears from experimentation that you do need at_exit if you want to delete the directory when program exits...

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139265/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-temporary-directory-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Its good to notice that you need to `require "tmpdir"`. Was not directly clear for me, as `Dir` is in core, but `Dir.mktmpdir` is not.

Comment: remove all the useless stuff from homebrew... Dir.mktmpdir does the job very well and remove the directory if you provide a block.

Comment: @Geoffroy yes, when provided with a block, `mktmpdir` will delete the directory after the block exits, but that was not what original question was asking for. The use case is quite different. Could you elaborate on "all the useless stuff from homebrew"?

Answer (score 17):

Use the [`Dir.mktmpdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html) method, from the stdlib:

```rb
require 'tmpdir'
Dir.mktmpdir do |d|
  File.open("#{d}/1.txt", 'w') do |f|
    f.write('1.txt') 
  end
end
# at this point 1.txt and the dir no longer exist
```