# ruby Temporary files inside temporary directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create temporary files inside temporary directory. below is my code for this.

```
           require 'tmpdir'
           require 'tempfile'
           Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
             Dir.chdir(dir)
             TemFile.new("f")
             sleep 20
           end
```

It gives me this exception:
`Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - C:/Users/SANJAY~1/AppData/Local/Temp/d20130724-5600-ka2ame` , because ruby is trying to delete a temp directory, which is not empty.

Please help me to create a temp file inside temp directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use the [Tempfile](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) class.

```ruby
require 'tempfile'

file = Tempfile.new('foo')
file.path      # => A unique filename in the OS's temp directory,
               #    e.g.: "/tmp/foo.24722.0"
               #    This filename contains 'foo' in its basename.
file.write("hello world")
file.rewind
file.read      # => "hello world"
file.close
file.unlink    # deletes the temp file
```

To create temporary folders, you can use [Dir.mktmpdir](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html#method-c-mktmpdir).

Comment: suppose i want to create 'foo' temp file inside temporary directory name 'testing' and this 'testing' directory should be deleted automatically once the request or session(irb seesion) expire.How you will do this?

Comment: Create a temp folder using [Dir.mktmpdir](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html#method-c-mktmpdir). You can see the questions '[How to create temp dir in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841660/how-to-create-temp-dir-in-ruby)' and '[What is the best way to get an empty temporary directory in Ruby on Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139265/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-an-empty-temporary-directory-in-ruby-on-rails)'.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. He asked to create a tempfile inside a tempfolder. Also do not give link as answer. What if ruby-doc changes of address ?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I created the temporary directory with the prefix "foo" and the tempfile with the prefix cats

```
dir = Dir.mktmpdir('foo')
begin      
  puts('Directory path:'+ dir) #Here im printing the path of the temporary directory

  # Creating the tempfile and giving as parameters the prefix 'cats' and 
  # the second parameter is the tempdirectory
  tempfile = Tempfile.new('cats', [tmpdir = dir]) 

  puts('File path:'+ tempfile.path)  #Here im printing the path of the tempfile
  tempfile.write("hello world")
  tempfile.rewind
  tempfile.read      # => "hello world"
  tempfile.close
  tempfile.unlink   
ensure
  # remove the directory.
  FileUtils.remove_entry dir
end
```

And since we print the paths on console we can get the following

```
Directory path: /tmp/foo20181116-9699-1o7jc6x
File path:  /tmp/foo20181116-9699-1o7jc6x/cats20181116-9699-7ofv1c
```